# Waswas of ejaculation of maniy

Tags: fiqh

Asalamualaikum pls what should I do I always have waswas  of ejaculating maniy  with out having erection and lust happens mostly before or during salah and I usually find no trace of maniy,but I feel movement in my genitals.pls what should I do

Answer (score 0):

Ignore it if you touch it this could happen don’t worry ignore now when you feel a wet spot and then you see semen that’s when you need to perform ghusl